# Attach a callback to a publish

Tags: javascript, dojo, callback, deferred

I was wondering whether anyone knew of a way to attach an event/callback to a dojo publish when the event that is published completes.

I am publishing something as a delegated task, and when the delegated task completes I want to make some UI changes.

Let me know if you know how or if you know that it's not possible.

---

EDIT: 
I guess I could also do what I wanted if I was able to return a value to the publisher after the event published finishes.

Comment: For those that proposed the deferred solution, I have a question. If I am going in and modifying the code of the subscriber, then wouldn't it be better to just have the subscriber publish an event when it finishes so the event is available to whoever might need it?

Comment: I think it all depends on what needs to know when the subscriber is done consuming the published message.  If only one thing (the original publisher) needs to do something, then maybe the use of `Deferred` would make the most sense.  If multiple disjoint entities need to perform some work when the subscriber is done consuming the message, then publishing to another topic might make the most sense.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Although the answers with deferred were nice and might be better practice, for my uses, since there is no real way to attach a callback, I am just going to publish a callback request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a "correct" way to do this but you could try using a separate channel and enforcing the connection "by convention":

```
dojo.subscribe('fooChannel', function(){
     ....
     dojo.publish('fooChannelComplete', [...]);
});
```

A helper function to make this more seamless:

```
function add_to_foo(f){
    dojo.subscribe('fooChannel', function(){
        var ret = f.apply(this, arguments);
        dojo.publish('fooChannelComplete', [ret]);
    });
}
```

Comment: I do have access to the function that I am publishing too, but I think that it could possibly get to messy so I think I will try to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try something like this

```
// publisher side
var d = new dojo.Deferred();
dojo.publish("my/channel",[d]);
// ... do some extra asynchronous work , server request ...
result = goterror ? "error" : "ok";
if (!error) d.callback(result); else d.errback(result);

// listener side
dojo.subscribe("my/channel",function(d) {
  // let's wait for the server to respond ( or maybe its already done )
  d.then(function(result) {
    // result is "ok"
  },function(params) {
    // result is "error"
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems like it might work. I will try it out when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Sebastien's premise:

```
//publisher
var deferred = new Dojo.deferred();
var successFunction = function(){
  console.log('task succesfully completed');
};

var errorFunction = function(){
  console.log('task did not succesfully complete');
};
//when our deferred object is done, invoke either successFunction or errorFunction
dojo.when(deferred, successFunction, errorFunction);

dojo.publish("someTopic",[deferred]);




//topic subscriber code
dojo.subscribe("someTopic",function(deferred) {
  //do whatever delegated task is needed.
  //...

  //task completed successfully, invoke the `successFunction` defined on the publisher
  deferred.callback();  

  //or if task did not complete successfully invoke `errorFunction` defined on the publisher
  //deferred.errback();

});
```

Same premise, but using `dojo.when` which IMO is nicer syntactic sugar.